# Mysql where is null being ignored? Why? How do i fix?

Tags: null

I have a table with

```
ID | product | cuid | file     | created    | start_date | cancelled  | brid   | price
123| prod3   | 1234 | filename | 2012-09-19 | 2012-09-19 | 2012-09-19 | broker | 20
124| prod1   | 1234 | filename | 2012-09-19 | 2012-09-19 | 0000-00-00 | broker | 10
125| prod1   | 1234 | filename | 2012-09-19 | 2012-09-19 | 0000-00-00 | broker | 10
126| prod3   | 1234 | filename | 2012-09-19 | 2012-09-19 | 0000-00-00 | broker | 20
```

created, start_date and cancelled are all DateTime columns.

Im running a query to work out the number of each product, the total cost for each product and a total price for all products using:

```
SELECT 
      count(product) as amount,
      product, 
      sum(price) AS price 
FROM `products` 
WHERE 
      brid = 'broker' 
AND 
      cancelled is null 
GROUP BY product 
WITH ROLLUP
```

This gives me

```
amount     | product            | price

2          | PROD1              | 20
2          | PROD3              | 40
4          | NULL               | 60
```

One of the PROD3 products has a date in the cancelled column, so the result should be

```
1          | PROD3              | 20
```

Adding and removing the 'cancelled is null' doesnt appear to make any difference to the results.
Also tried 'cancelled = "0000-00-00 00:00:00"' which didnt affect the results...

Any ideas how i restrict this to only products that havent been cancelled?

Any help please!

Answer (score 0):

You should put `AND cancelled IS NOT NULL`

Comment: No problem! :) It's happening to anyone of us :)